# C# How do I link a child form to a parent?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows form application that has a child form that pops up for data entry, when you hit 'Save' the child form closes. However if I don't close the child form and click on another program e.g. Outlook, OUtlook comes to the top but my child form remains above Outlook. Do I need to link it to the parent so they can't be seperated?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to a MDI application?

Comment: No it's a simple pop-up window that you enter data in and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data entry dialog is being created with the [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property set to true.

This will make it stay on op of all other windows who are not themselves set to top most (most of them). This is normally annoying to end users and very few dialogs actually merit its use.